# Constrained Least squares problem. Help

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares

I have a system $Y=X\beta$ and I am looking for the Least squares solution (or some optimal solution) of $\beta$, but certain constraints over $\beta$ must be fulfilled. $Y$ is a matrix $(100\times3)$, $X$ is also $(100\times3)$ and $\beta$ is a square matrix $(3\times3)$. $X$ and $Y$ are non negative, and all elements of beta are between $0$ and $1$). The constraints to this problem are:

1. The rows of $\beta$ must sum up to one (I mean, the sum of the elements for each row must be equal to one $\sum_j\beta_{i,j}=1$).
2. Each element of $\beta$ is restricted to certain interval: $a_{ij}\leq\beta_{ij}\leq b_{ij}$ but still within the range [0,1]. (the intervals are long enough that still allow for the first constraint to be satisfied.

\

Update -----------------------------------------------------

Up until now, starting to solve the problem with just the first constraint, I have come up with the idea of multiplying $\beta$ by a matrix of ones and make it equal to that "ones" matrix. Then my minimization function is looking like this:

$J(\beta,\lambda)=|Y-X\beta|^2 + \lambda^T(A\beta^T-A)$; with $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow J(\beta,\lambda)=Y^TY-2\beta^TX^TY+\beta^TX^TX\beta + \lambda^T(A\beta^T-A)$

When applying Lagrangian multipliers method, I got the next equation system:

$(1)\ \frac{\partial J}{\partial\beta}=-2Y^TX+2X^TX\beta+A\lambda=0$

$(2)\  \frac{\partial J}{\partial\lambda}=\beta A-A=0$

And when solving for beta (from equation 1) and replacing it into equation 2 to get lambda:

$(X^TX)^{-1}Y^TX-\frac{1}{2}(X^TX)^{-1}A\lambda=\beta$

$(X^TX)^{-1}Y^TXA-\frac{1}{2}(X^TX)^{-1}A\lambda A=A$

The problem I have is that I don´t really know how to solve this system, or even if it is well formulated at all or if the use of this "A" matrix be the right approach to include the first constraint. And also still need to figure it out how to include the constraint 2.

I really appreciate any help someone can give to solve this. Or a reference that I can research on. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ nonnegative?

Comment: yes both are non negative

Comment: From a practical standpoint you might consider an alternative to least-squares, constrained optimization of $J := \sum_{i,j}\,Y_{ij}\log\frac{Y_{ij}}{\sum_k\, X_{ik}\beta_{kj}}$. Solution is iterative. Not what you asked for though. 

Comment: That sounds interesting, thanks!. What is the name of that method?

Comment: Any reason for not using standard methods in constrained least-squares, i.e. most directly just use a standard QP solver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Collect the lower/upper interval bounds into matrices
$$(a_{ij},\,b_{ij})\to(A,B)$$
Then given an unconstrained matrix $U,\,$ you can construct a matrix which satisfies the second constraint using elementwise multiplication $(\odot)$
$$\eqalign{
W &= \fracLR{B+A}{2} + \fracLR{B-A}{2}\odot \tanh(U) \\
-\infty&\le U_{ij}\le \infty \;\qiq A_{ij}\le W_{ij}\le B_{ij} \\
}$$
where the hyperbolic tangent can be replaced by any sigmoid function whose output range is normalized $\in[-\o,\o].\,$ The tangent is nice because it has a simple differential
$$\eqalign{
H &= \tanh(U) \\
dH &= (J-H\odot H)\odot dU \\
}$$
Subsequently, the first constraint can be satisfied using
the all-ones matrix $(J)$ and elementwise division $(\oslash)$
$$\eqalign{
\b &= W\oslash WJ \;=\; \Diag{W\o}^{-1}W \\
\b\o &= \o \\
}$$
Calculate the gradient of the least-squares objective with respect to the unconstrained variable
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac 12\|X\b-Y\|_F^2 \\
d\phi &= \CLR{X^TX\b-X^TY}:d\b \\
 &= \c{P}:d\b \\
 &= P:\LR{dW\oslash WJ - \b\oslash WJ\odot dW\,J} \\
 &= \LR{P\oslash WJ}:dW - \LR{P\odot\b\oslash WJ}:dW\,J \\
 &= \BR{P\oslash WJ-\LR{\b\odot P\oslash WJ}J}:dW \\
 &= \BR{P\oslash WJ-\LR{\b\odot P\oslash WJ}J}:\fracLR{B-A}{2}\odot\LR{J-H\odot H}\odot dU \\
 &= \BR{P\oslash WJ-\LR{\b\odot P\oslash WJ}J}\odot\fracLR{B-A}{2}\odot\LR{J-H\odot H}:dU \\
\grad{\phi}{U}
 &= \BR{P\oslash WJ-\LR{\b\odot P\oslash WJ}J}\odot\fracLR{B-A}{2}\odot\LR{J-H\odot H} \\
}$$
This gradient expression is so complicated that there's probably not a closed form solution for $U$ which yields a zero-gradient.

However, you can use this gradient in any gradient descent method to *numerically* calculate the optimal $U$ matrix, after which you can calculate the corresponding $W$ and $\b$ matrices.

---

In some of the steps above, a colon is used to denote the matrix inner product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$

### Update

Based on the discussion in the comments, you cannot satisfy both constraints by clever construction. However, keeping the $(A,B)$ construction
$$\eqalign{
 \b &= \fracLR{B-A}{2}\odot \tanh(U) + \fracLR{B+A}{2} \\
d\b &= \c{\fracLR{B-A}{2}\odot\BR{J-H\odot H}}\odot dU \\
   &= \c{R}\odot dU \\
}$$
and adding the simpler constraint to the objective function yields
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{\l}2\|X\b-Y\|_F^2 \;+\; \tfrac 12\|\b\o-\o\|_F^2 \\
d\phi &= \l P:d\b \;+\; \CLR{\b J-J}:d\b \\
 &= \LR{\l P + \c{Q}}:\LR{R\odot dU} \\
\grad{\phi}{U}
 &= \LR{\l P + Q}\odot R \\
}$$
This gradient represents an *unconstrained* problem which can be solved by **any** gradient descent method for various values of the $\l$ parameter.
The $\l$ parameter controls the relative importance of satisfying the original objective function versus the constraint.

Comment: Ohh thanks, that is a very nice approach!, specially for how you formulate $\beta$. However, I have two questions. 1) I understand the formulation of $\beta=W\oslash WJ$ normalizes every row of $\beta$ to fulfill constraint 1, which is great, but what does ensure that once you do the row normalization, the elements of $\beta$ will be still within the required ranges A and B?. Because W elements will be within range but after normalizing perhaps they could be out of it, or may I be wrong?. And 2) is the $1$ you wrote next to $\beta$ an all-ones matrix just as J?

Comment: @MathStatsFor 1) You're right.  Constructing a matrix to satisfy the second constraint will violate the first constraint.  So I'd suggest using the $\beta$-construction for the first constraint, and then using an optimization method which specifically handles box constraints, e.g. _L-BFGS-B_ or Projected gradient descent.    2) The symbol $\tt1$ is the all-ones vector and $J={\tt11}^T$ is the all-ones matrix. Although $\beta J=J$ is also a true statement.

Comment: Great. I will look for those methods. Thank you so much!! @greg

Comment: Thanks for your update, Regarding that, I´ve been thinking, if you enforce box constraints over W, still the elements of $\beta$ can be out of range because of the normalization that comes after, or may I be wrong?. I´ve thinking that perhaps one way to reduce the impact of the normalization over the elements of $\beta$ is by assigning virtually short ranges such that when the elements be off those short limits still be within the real ranges. I know that this could be a workaround, but I will let you know if it works 